# Set charset to file with ruby

Tags: ruby, file, encoding, character-encoding

I try to write a file into a utf-8 charset file. When I do

```
    File.open("#{POST_XML_PATH}/#{filename}", 'w:utf-8) { |f| f.write(my_xml.to_xml) }
```

I get with file - I application/xml; charset=us-ascii

How change the charset to utf-8 ? I also tried to make a .encode('utf-8) on my my_xml var

Thank you

EDIT:

```
my_xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: 'UTF-8') do |xml|
xml.Envelope(xmlns: 'http://test.com') {
xml.FileInfos {
  xml.FileID id
  xml.FileDate current_time.try(:strftime, '%Y%m%d')
  xml.FileTime current_time.try(:strftime, '%H%M%S')
  xml.Customer {
    xml.Number '123456'
    xml.Name1 "Name1"
    xml.Street "Street 1"
    xml.ZIP "1000"
    xml.City "Geneve"
    xml.Country "CH"
  }
}
}

File.open("#{POST_XML_PATH}/#{filename}", 'w') { |f| f.write(my_xml.to_xml) }
```

If I add 'Genève' the charset is UTF-8, So ruby determine charset if needed. But I want always utf-8

Comment: change `'w:utf-8'` to `'w:us-ascii:utf-8'`... Let me know the result.

Comment: @ArupRakshit no change ...

Comment: Are you using nokogiri ? Give some more code to see, what exactly you doing.

Comment: 'w:utf-8' should work correctly, I checked your code with 'w:utf-8' it is working fine and using UTF-8 encoding only. On ubuntu + ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Just change `f.write(my_xml.to_xml)` to `f.write(my_xml.to_xml(:encoding => 'UTF-8'))`.. Now don't need `'w:us-ascii:utf-8'`.. this to do.

Comment: I edited my post. So even if w:utf-8 AND to_xml(:encoding => 'UTF-8'), that's still us-ascii. But with 'é' it's utf-8

Comment: I used your code ubuntu with ruby-19.2

# encoding: UTF-8
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
require 'nokogiri'
my_xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: 'UTF-8') do |xml|
xml.Envelope(xmlns: 'http://test.com') {
  xml.FileInfos {
    xml.FileID 1
    xml.FileDate Time.now.try(:strftime, '%Y%m%d')
    xml.FileTime Time.now.try(:strftime, '%H%M%S')
    xml.Customer {
      xml.Number '123456'
      ...
    }
  }
}
end
File.open("test.txt", "w:us-ascii:utf-8") do |f| 
  f.write(my_xml.to_xml)
end

Comment: O/P 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://test.com">
  <FileInfos>
    <FileID>1</FileID>
    <FileDate>20140228</FileDate>
    <FileTime>170114</FileTime>
    <Customer>
      <Number>123456</Number>
      <Name1>Name1</Name1>
      <Street>Street 1</Street>
      <ZIP>1000</ZIP>
      <City>Geneve</City>
      <Country>CH</Country>
    </Customer>
  </FileInfos>
</Envelope>

Comment: @AlokAnand Humm `'w:us-ascii:utf-8'` works for you.. happy to see :-)

Comment: even 'w:utf-8' works fine and returns UTF-8 encoding
File.open("test.txt", "w:utf-8") do |f| 
  f.write(my_xml.to_xml)
end